# grep a column for two digit number

Tags: regex, grep

I have a csv file which contains logs of different users. I need to view the records for particular used id using grep.

[image]

The output I need is User id '37' in the first column and all the entries of this user id. have spent a lot of time on this.

I specifically need to use ' grep' for this.

I am using- grep "^37" file.

This gives me all the entries for user ids starting with 37. I just need 37.

Comment: Did you try `grep ^37\s` ?  (line starting with 37 followed by a space-character)

Comment: How is this question related to python-3.x?

Comment: grep "^37\b" should do the job, \b for word boundary

Comment: Impossible to tell on that picture what is the field delimiter. Don't post sample data as images, post it as text along with its expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo López's comment is a valid answer, here's my take on it:

```
grep "^37[^0-9]"
```

You are looking for the digits (`37`) at the beginning (`^`) of a line, followed by a delimiter (not followed by other digits).
`[^0-9]` matches any character that isn't a digit.

Don't hesitate to write down your thought process, what you are looking for, it will make finding the right regex easier. Try to find examples, counter examples, etc.
You should also read grep's `man` page, or check out one of the many `grep` tutorials. Try [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/).